# Numbering permutations of $1\ldots N$ from $1$ to $N!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a permutation of $1$ to $N$, I'd like to assign it a unique number from $1$ to $N!$, e.g., for $N=3$ maybe $<1,2,3>\to1\ \ldots\ <3,2,1>\to6$. But numbering doesn't have to be in any particular order. Purpose is just to check the randomness of a little random permutation generator program.

Not necessary, but if curious, here it is (check would be added to test driver at bottom)...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* ==========================================================================
 * Function:    int permutation ( int seed, int n, int *p )
 * Purpose:     Returns p[0]...p[n-1] containing 1...n arranged randomly
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Arguments:   seed (I)        int optionally containing seed for srandom(),
 *                              if 0 or negative, srandom() not called
 *              n (I)           int containing rank of permutation
 *              p (O)           &int returning 1...n arranged randomly
 * Returns:     ( int )         n=success, 0=failure
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Notes:     o
 * ======================================================================= */
/* --- entry point --- */
int     permutation ( int seed, int n, int *p ) {
  /* --- Allocations and Declarations --- */
  int   i=0;                            /* p[] index */
  /* --- Initialization --- */
  if ( n<1 || p==NULL ) { n=0; goto end_of_job; } /* input error */
  if ( seed > 0 ) srandom(seed);        /* initialize random() */
  for ( i=0; i<n; i++ ) p[i] = i+1;     /* initialize p[0...n-1] = 1...n */
  /* ---
   * Generate random permutation
   * ------------------------------ */
  for ( i=0; i<n-1; i++ ) {
    int j = i + ((random())%(n-i));     /* random i <= j <= n-1 */
    int pi = p[i];                      /* swap p[i] <--> p[j] */
    p[i] = p[j];                        /* p[i] = p[j] */
    p[j] = pi; }                        /* p[j] = p[i] */
  end_of_job:
    return ( n );                       /* back to caller */
  } /* --- end-of-function permutation() --- */

/* ---
 * Test Driver
 * -------------- */
#if defined(TESTDRIVE)
int     main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  int   n    = (argc>1? atoi(argv[1]) : 16 ), /* rank of permutation */
        seed = (argc>2? atoi(argv[2]) : 7654321 ); /* srandom() seed */
  int   permutation(), p[9999],         /* random permutation of 1...n */
        i=0;                            /* p[] index */
  if(n<0)n=16;  if(n>999)n=999;         /* sanity check */
  permutation(seed,n,p);                /* generate permutation */
  for ( i=0; i<n; i++ )                 /* print results */
    printf("%5d%s",p[i],((i+1)%10==0||i==n-1?"\n":", "));
  } /* --- end-of-function main() --- */
#endif
```

**____ E D I T ____**

Based on @Peter's comment below, and as per my followup comment, I studied that perm_to_Z_inplace() function from the PARI/GP library, and came up with the following code illustrated below. Unfortunately, it's not easily expressible in any algebraic form (not as far as I can tell, anyway), and I still don't fully understand how/why it works (so the comments aren't really explaining what's going on), but was nevertheless able to rewrite it recursively, a bit shorter than the original, and in such a way so that it doesn't destroy the original input (which the PARI/GP version does)...

```
/* ==========================================================================
 * Function:    permrank ( n, p )
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Purpose:   o Calculates the rank (index 1...n!)
 *              of the permutation of 1,2,3,...,n given in p[].
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Arguments:   n (I)           int containing number of items in p[]
 *              p (I)           int *  containing some permutation of
 *                              1,2,3,...,n whose rank (index 1...n!)
 *                              is to be determined.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Returns:     (int)           rank (index 1...n!) corresponding to p[]
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Notes:     o
 * ======================================================================= */
/* --- entry point --- */
int     permrank ( int n, int *p ) {
  int   i=0, fact=1, rank=0;
  if ( n == 1 ) return ( 1 );   /* rank=1 always for perm with 1 element */
  while ( ++i < n ) {
    if ( p[i] < p[0] ) rank++;  /* rank=0 if p[0] is least, etc. */
    fact *= i; }                /* accumulate (n-1)! */
  return ( rank*fact + permrank(n-1,p+1) );  /* recurse on rest of perm */
  } /* --- end-of-function permrank() --- */
```

Note that for this preliminary testing it's just using ints for integers, meaning that the maximum $n$ is $12$ (assuming signed $32$-bit ints) since $12!=479,001,600$ (and $13$ is just plain unlucky).

By the way, in case you're interested and can't read the code, let me add the following brief description: Let $p_i,i=1\ldots n$ denote the sequence of $n$ integers comprising some permutation of $1,2,3,\ldots,n$. Now, let $c_i$ denote a count of those $p_j:\ j>i\ \&\ p_j<p_i$, i.e., count those numbers after $p_i$ in the sequence whose value is less than $p_i$. Then the rank $1\ldots n!$ returned by permrank() above is $1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}c_i\times(n-i)!\ $. So, for the unpermuted sequence $1,2,3,\ldots,n-1,n$ the rank is $1$, and reversing the last two numbers $1,2,3,\ldots,n,n-1$ gives $2$, and the completely reversed $n,n-1,\ldots,3,2,1$ gives $n!$. That's what it does, but what I can't see is why it works.

Comment: PARI/GP has a command allowing to assign a number to a permutation, but I guess you need a description of the algorithm , unless you can test your generator directly with PARI/GP.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, Peter, that should answer the question. Never heard of that package before, but googled it and downloaded the source from http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html Then quickly found src/basemath/perm.c containing the function permtonum(). Guess what that does:)  Actually, it just calls perm_to_Z_inplace() which in turn calls some other stuff,... Presumably that ends somewhere, with an ultimately easy-to-understand algorithm, which I'll just reprogram more directly and transparently once I figure it all out. Thanks, again.

Comment: @Peter Okay, PARI/GP indeed solved the problem (at least with respect to a programmed solution, though I'm still not sure why it algebraically works), and my reprogrammed version of the PARI/GP function is illustrated above. Thanks, again.

Comment: Have you heard about the [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) ?

Comment: Connection with [Lehmer code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the very useful mathematical references (no, I hadn't heard of them). Google hadn't coughed up this kind of stuff when I originally checked before posting the question. Thought I'd tried an adequate selection of search terms (don't recall what anymore), but apparently not. Merci bien.

Comment: Happy it has helped. Another interesting "mathematical being" that you have maybe heard of: the [permutohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron)